# External Monitor, Touch Pad, and Sound Not Working After Installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, multiple-monitors, touchpad, hdmi

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows on my brand new Acer Aspire 5 laptop, many things are not working. During the installation I checked the box to install third party drivers so I'm hoping this didn't cause this to happen. But basically:

- My external monitor is not recognized at all after plugging it in through HDMI. It is a ViewSonic monitor.
- My sound does not work on my laptop, it comes up as "Dummy Output". Bluetooth does work through my headphones however
- The touchpad (which has a fingerprint scanner) does not work either

Any help would be appreciated. I am basically forced to use Windows until this is resolved because this is really inconvenient to my work station.

Cheers!

Comment: Update: If I close my laptop and dual boot into Ubuntu, my external monitor then works. If I open my laptop however, that screen doesn't display anything. Additionally, Ubuntu does not recognize my microphone. I need to be able to code and go to a Zoom meeting without switching to Windows, so if I can get that working I can at least use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Thinkbook 13s Gen 2 ITL and had similar problems. I solved the trackpad and external monitor issue by upgrading to the most recent kernel (other kernels likely work as well, but I did not test them). I'll post again when I figure out the sound issue.

One can find the kernel .deb packages at [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) (using `wget` and `dpkg` to download and install). Because I'm less familiar with the kernel packages required, I used [mainline](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline), which is a fork of ukuu.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

Launching mainline, I used the GUI to install kernel 5.10.2 (seems to be the most recent at the time of writing). Post install, a reboot is required.

I hope this helps you too. Cheers

Comment: Hello, after doing this, I got the following error after selecting Ubuntu from the grub menu: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.3-051003-generic has invalid signature. you need to load the kernel first.

Comment: update: after disabling secure boot in my UEFI firmware settings I am able to load the new kernel. Everything works now, including my audio! Thank you very much!